# Finding 2D array length?

Tags: java, arrays

I know that array.length returns the number of rows, but I'm looking for the length of each row.  Apparently array[0].length doesnt do it.  Any ideas?

Comment: offhand it seems like it should, *if* it's been initialized. do you get an exception? if not, what are you getting for the length?

Comment: I get the same length for array[0].length as I do for array.length.

Comment: and it's *not* the same length in reality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
jcomeau@intrepid:~/rentacoder$ cat /tmp/test.java 
public class test {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  int[][] blah = {{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}};
  System.out.println("lengths: " + blah.length + ", " + blah[0].length +
   ", " + blah[1].length);
 }
}
jcomeau@intrepid:~/rentacoder$ (cd /tmp && java test)
lengths: 2, 2, 3
```

Seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

In Java there are only one-dimensional arrays internally.

A two-dimensional array is an array of arrays, so the array for the first dimension and each of the arrays for the second dimension may have a different size.